# Oozie java action configured parameter?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am trying to migrate a existing MR code to Oozie.

currently it is executed something like below command

'hadoop jar myMR.jar  -Dmapred.inputformat.class=abc inputarg1 inputarg2'

As it has java arguments,  I cann't use OOZIE MR action directly , instead I am trying to use Java action , but couldn't find out a way to pass  '-Dmapred.inputformat.class=abc' as a configured value.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

should look something like this :

```
<action name='MyJavaActionName'>
        <java>
            <main-class>my.package.MyClassName</main-class>
            <arg>arg1</arg>
            <arg>arg2</arg>
            <arg>arg3</arg>
            <capture-output />
        </java>
        <ok to="email-success" />
        <error to="email-fail" />
    </action>
```

Hope it's help !

Comment: The `<arg>` tags are used to pass arguments to `main()`, not to the MR configuration as was being asked for.

Answer (score 0):

For the MR property you should add a configuration property to your Java action, like so:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.inputformat.class</name>
        <value>abc</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```